# how to implement Handle,JniIdentityHashCode,PeerReference,JniPeerMembers,JniManagedPeerState on xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Good day , how can I implement the functions below? on xamarin

```
  public IntPtr Handle => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public int JniIdentityHashCode => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public JniObjectReference PeerReference => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public JniPeerMembers JniPeerMembers => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public JniManagedPeerStates JniManagedPeerState => throw new NotImplementedException();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In xamarin, if we implement interface, we need to inherit from class `Java.Lang.Object` as well as the interface itself,just as Trevor Balcom mentioned.

Suppose your interface is `ITestClientListener`,we can do like this:

```
public class TestClientListener : Java.Lang.Object, ITestClientListener
{
    public JniManagedPeerStates JniManagedPeerState()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    IntPtr ITestClientListener.Handle()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    int ITestClientListener.JniIdentityHashCode()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    JniPeerMembers ITestClientListener.JniPeerMembers()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    JniObjectReference ITestClientListener.PeerReference()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And we can use it's instance like this:

```
//create a new object
TestClientListener listener = new TestClientListener();

// use it as you need
```

Note:

You need to add necessary codes in above methods in class `TestClientListener .cs` if it required.

Answer (score 1):

Your C# object in the Android project should inherit from `Java.Lang.Object`.

```cs
public class YourCSharpObject : Java.Lang.Object
{
}
```